# Sending an array with hidden field to the controller using jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I want to send an array to the controller using jquery. Continuous data is going on. I want to go to the controller as a list or as an array. Who can help me?

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, string[] items)
        {
            LocationDBEntities db = new LocationDBEntities();
            List<Map> mapList = new List<Map>();
            if (Request != null)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];
                if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                {
                    string fileName = file.FileName;
                    string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/FileUpload"), file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                        {
                            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                            var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                            var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                            var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                            var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                            for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                            {
                                var map = new Map();
                                map.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
                                for (int i = 0; i < noOfRow; i++)
                                {
                                    map.Latitude = items[i];
                                    map.Longitude = items[i];
                                }                           
                                map.Address = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in mapList)
            {
                db.Map.Add(item);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(mapList);
```

This is my javascript code:

```
var liste, i, listeUzunluk;
    liste = [
       { lat: lat },
       { lng: lng }
    ];
    listeUzunluk = liste.length;
    for (i = 0; i < listeUzunluk; i++) {
        console.log(liste[i]);
        document.getElementById("items").value = liste[i];
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong? What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSTo.png)

Comment: You could just do `document.getElementById("items").value=JSON.stringify(liste)` then decode that json server side back into an array

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion but I could not reach the desired result. I have to pass it to the controller as a list or array.

Comment: It is, it's json which is a very very common data format

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It could also be the json list. I need to be able to return as a list or as an array. But it brings a single record. You can look at the picture for an example.

Comment: That is a  json array with one object in it. Nothing shown in question to indicate how `liste` is populated. The outer braces are `[]` which denotes array

Comment: What do I have to do in this situation?